# Как заблокировать подключенные устройства в win7-win10

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, hook

Необходимо заблокировать все USB устройства и разрешить только те которые указаны в белом листе. В msdn прады не нашёл, и на форумах на эту тему молчат, с чего начать?
   т.к. система должна работать и на моменте загрузки ОС то это должен быть драйвер или сервис тоже подойдёт для этой задачи?

Comment: кажется тут нужно winAPI, вам нужно капать в эту http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453082/c-winapi-get-list-of-all-connected-usb-devices и эту стороны http://www.realcoding.net/articles/rabota-s-usb-ustroistvami.html

Answer (score -3):

Под устройствами из белого листа подразумеваются определенные имена usb-накопителей? Тогда лучше лочить через антивирус, каспер с этим справляется на ура. Если блокировка должна распространяться на ПК в домене, то через gpo можно стандартными политиками, либо измененниями в реестре.

Comment: это не должно быть сторонее ПО или политики ОС, только собственное ПО